# Which GUI is used to make notepad++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, notepad++

I figured out today that `notepad++` is built using `C++`. But much confused which GUI is used by `Notepad++`, does it use own `GUI` platforms? or what?

Comment: it says so straight on the frontpage `Based on the powerful editing component Scintilla, Notepad++ is written in C++ and uses pure Win32 API and STL`. It's pure Win32 API, no other GUI toolkit

Comment: You can even download the source code and look for yourself.

Comment: Then for `linux` what does it use, In my opinion, linux doesn't support `win32 API`.. ?

Comment: There is no native linux version of Notepad++.

Comment: @rajsharma you can use Win32 API implementations like Wine under Linux to run Notepad++ and the Scintilla portion also has gtk, qt and cocoa backends but the rest of Notepad++ doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

It uses `Windows API`, which can be found from the source code, such as [PowerEditor/src/winmain.cpp](http://svn.tuxfamily.org/viewvc.cgi/notepadplus_repository/trunk/PowerEditor/src/winmain.cpp?revision=1236&view=markup).

In addition, you can find the Owner-drawing widget at [WinControls](http://svn.tuxfamily.org/viewvc.cgi/notepadplus_repository/trunk/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/). So we can call it `own GUI platforms` to some extent.